# Wordpress wp query to retrieve and echo featured image from first post in category

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to create a 'strange' query to retrieve the first post from a category and echo the featured image URL - wrapped in img html tags.

Don't ask why I'm doing it this way. I think my query below should theoretically work, I think it's bad syntax in my php as it breaks page - can anyone please help me fix?

```
<?php

    $featureThumb       = new WP_Query(array(

    'post_type'         => 'post',
    'order'             => 'DESC',
    'orderby'           => 'date',
    'posts_per_page'    => 1,
    'cat'               => 4

));

if ($featureThumb->has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)) {

    $retina  = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'homepage-thumb-retina' );

    echo '<img src="' . $retina[0] . '" alt="' . the_title() . '" width="24" height="24" />' ;

};

endwhile;

unset($featureThumb);

endif; wp_reset_query();

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
<?php
$featureThumb = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'         => 'post',
    'order'             => 'DESC',
    'orderby'           => 'date',
    'posts_per_page'    => 1,
    'cat'               => 4
));

while ($featureThumb->have_posts()) : $featureThumb->the_post();
    if (has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)) {
        $retina  = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'homepage-thumb-retina' );
        echo '<img src="' . $retina[0] . '" alt="' . the_title() . '" width="24" height="24" />' ;
    };
endwhile;

unset($featureThumb);

wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much dude!!! Can see where I was going wrong. Did not think I needed the while, but makes sense now to retrieve the post first.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe somthing like this

```
        $postsQuery       = new WP_Query(array(

    'post_type'         => 'post',
    'order'             => 'DESC',
    'orderby'           => 'date',
    'posts_per_page'    => 1,
    'cat'               => 4

));

while ( $postsQuery->have_posts() ) 
{
        $postsQuery->the_post();
if(has_post_thumbnail($post->ID))
{

    $retina  = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'homepage-thumb-retina' );

    echo '<img src="' . $retina[0] . '" alt="' . the_title() . '" width="24" height="24" />' ;

};
}



unset($postsQuery);

wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: Hey dude thanks for taking the time, this will also probably worked. Cheers